# klarna-placement::part(osm-container) stopped working (Sept 27 2023)

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, shadow-dom, klarna

Does anyone knows why the ::part() styles are not applying to a component

I have the following element:
[klarna-placement html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaBfB.png)

Then following [this doc](https://docs.klarna.com/on-site-messaging/in-depth-knowledge/styling-on-site-messaging-with-css/), I added the following styles

`klarna-placement::part(osm-container) { border: none; padding: 0; }`

Last week when I did the code, I was even able to preview it by adding the css code directly into the dev tools. But today, the styles are not getting applied, and doing anything in the dev tools don't do anything at all.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there anything that klarna might have don't that would've prevented the browser to style the parts? Or is this a new bug in all browsers?

Thanks in advance for your help

I've tried !important, using the id of the element like:
`#klarna-pdp::part(osm-container) { border: none; padding: 0; }`

but nothing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced same issue, on previous day css were applied but on other day changes weren't getting applied
Solution worked for me both in devtool and in code base is: leaving a space before '::'.
klarna-placement ::part(osm-badge) {
width: 43.146px!important;
height: 24px
}